# How to set up mako templates with Flask to yield decipherable exceptions?

Tags: python, flask, mako

I like mako and wish it were easier to integrate with the Flask framework. I setup the [flask-mako](https://github.com/tzellman/flask-mako) extension but quickly discovered that instead of the very nice [flask debugger screen](http://kay-docs.shehas.net/_images/debugger.png) producing an easily understood traceback like it did with jinja, I get an almost useless version with little descriptions and inaccurate line numbers (I'd provide some hard evidence, but I have already uninstalled).

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390409/how-do-you-debug-mako-templates) describes a way to setup mako with better exception handling, which I assume was my problem, but from what I can tell, it looks like I would need to run a try/except on every one of my url functions?

Isn't there a way to turn this exception handling "always on" so the flask debugger will be usable without all this extra effort?

Several places mention how easy it is to swap jinja/mako in flask, but I am finding that is not the case. Hopefully I'm missing something...

Answer (score 0):

flask-mako is a very simple package.  Instead of wrapping every one of your render calls with try: except:, I suggest that you instead fork flask-mako, and in flaskext/mako.py wrap the render call (line 53 on the current master) with the mako try except.  A quick pass at doing so can be found at: https://github.com/jd-boyd/flask-mako

However, while that makes the error in the mako template much easier to find, it still does not let you use the flask debugger to debug mako templates.