# debugging Mako templates in Pyramid

Tags: debugging, pyramid, mako

This is related to this question:  [How do you debug Mako templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390409/how-do-you-debug-mako-templates)

[One response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390409/how-do-you-debug-mako-templates#answer-536087) mentions the built in [debugging system in Mako](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/usage.html#handling-exceptions) and [there's a comment about how it works well in Pyramid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390409/how-do-you-debug-mako-templates#comment-6382443).  However, I have no idea how you'd incorporate what is mentioned into Pyramid as you never call Mako's template rendering method directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a pyramid setting to catch mako exceptions.

- [mako.error_handler](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/environment.html#mako-error-handler)

A small pyramid extensions targeting mako exceptions in pyramid.

- [pyramid_weberror](https://github.com/blaflamme/pyramid_weberror)

If you want to get in touch with mako rendering method directly, you can go for a mako preprocessor.

- [mako.preprocessor](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/environment.html#mako-preprocessor)

sample code for this approach.

- [Add possibility to specify a mako preprocessor](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/pull/183)